# ASP.NET: urls in plain html files can't find app root

Tags: asp.net, html, hyperlink, root

A client I'm working with insists on including a plain-jane html file in the ASP.NET app and I can't get the link urls to work properly. Here's an example:

```
<li><a class="nav_history2" href="/history.html">History</a></li>
```

It finds the server root (as I expect) but how to modify it to respect the app root? I'm looking for an equivalent to the ~. The client has tried ../ but claims it still finds the root. How is that possible? What SHOULD it look like please?

I don't have the ability to run it on his prod server, so I can't see the problem directly.

----- Edit -----

If I follow the suggestions given in the first two answers it will work if I turn the html page into an aspx, but so far not in the raw html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you just need to make ASP.NET actively aware of the tag, and the ~ symbol will work.  Try:

```
<a class="nav_history2" runat="server" href="~/history.html">
```

Comment: It seems the html file needs to be converted to an aspx first. I guess that's reasonable - surely the ~ has no meaning outside the context of an aspx page.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that bit - correct, it must be ASPX.  HTML is served up unprocessed.